# Does Referring to an Object without creating a variable for it in a std::vector create a new instance of that object?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a vector of objects in heap, which I created via

```
auto a = std::make_shared<std::vector<MyClass>>();
```

I placed several instances of MyClass inside that vector, through calls to

```
a->push_back(MyClass());
```

To my understanding, the above creates an instance of MyClass on stack, then copies it to a, in heap memory.

So at this point, both the vector and the objects are living within heap memory.

My question is, if I were to call

```
a->at(0).myMethod();
```

Would that copy MyObject to stack, then call the method? Or would it call the method on the object directly?

Comment: What does `at()` return?  That would answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::vector::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) returns reference to the element, then the method is called on the element directly, no temporary object gets copied here.

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos, with bounds checking.

Answer (score 1):

> To my understanding, the above creates an instance of MyClass on stack, then copies it to a, in heap memory.

Not in C++17 or later. And prior to that the implementation is specifically permitted to elide the copy, constructing in the vector's allocation.